# Text Field shows twice in JOptionPane.showInputDialog. Why?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, joptionpane

So, I'm creating a simple dialog to get user input, but the text field shows twice. Here's an SSCCE.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextField fileName = new JTextField();
    Object[] message = {"File name", fileName};
    String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message, "Add New", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    System.out.println(fileName.getText());
}
```

[image]

What's wrong with the code here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is doing so because you are adding `JTextField` object also in `message[]`.

`Object[] message = {"File name", fileName};//sending filename as message`
 So , the first `JTextField` shown is inherent one from inputDialog and other one is your own `JTextField` that you are sending as message .

What I guess is that you want to send the content of `fileName` to message. In that case your code should be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextField fileName = new JTextField();
    Object[] message = {"File name", fileName.getText()};//send text of filename
    String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message, "Add New", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    System.out.println(fileName.getText());
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you want only to take input then there is no need to send object `filename` as message. You should simply proceed as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //JTextField fileName = new JTextField();
        Object[] message = {"File name"};
        String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message, "Add New", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (option == null)
        System.out.println("Cancell is clicked..");
        else
        System.out.println(option+ " is entered by user");
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I want to get the input from user. But that explains.

Comment: If you want only input from use then don't send `filename` as message .. `JOptionPane.inputDialog` does this automatically for you.

Comment: So how do I check whether user clicked Ok or Cancel?

Comment: @user2059238 See my updated code. in short .. if `option` is `null` it means user has `cancelled` else user has entered some value.

Comment: Aha.. and just to add here, `option.length() == 0` is also required.

Answer (score 2):

Input dialog by default contains text field so you don't need to add another one. Try maybe this way

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "File name",
        "Add New", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: So how do I check whether user clicked Ok or Cancel?

Comment: @user2059238 If user clicked Cancel `name` would be `null`. You can test if with `if (name==null)` or even better `if (name==null || name.isEmpty())` in case user clicked OK without typing anything.